# check for a filename and use it in a filepath?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

CustomerName is a string that's being populated from a database value.

I would like to check if a file exists with that particular name in a directory and, if it does, use it as a file path. For example:

```
CustomerName = "James Doe"
```

Assuming it exists in the `images` folder, I'd like to store it in a variable:

```
string filepath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\images\\James Doe.png);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the capability to use wild cards (for example if the file extension in unknown), you need to use `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles`.

```
string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~\\images");
string filePattern = String.Format("{0}.*", CustomerName);
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, filePattern);
if (files.Length > 0)
{
    //here you can check which file(s) was returned and the corresponding extension.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the File.Exists method to check it.

```
string filePath = httpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(string.Format(@"~\images\{0}.png", CustomerName);
if (File.Exists(filePath)
{
    do.something()
}
```

Comment: thank you code warrior..but the problem is the file format may vary.it can be a jpeg file or png or jpg...how can i get the path then..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
string filepath = Server.MapPath("~\\images\\" + CustomerName +".png");
if (File.Exists(filePath))
{
//do sth
}
```

Comment: thank you Adrian ..but the problem is the file format may vary.it can be a jpeg file or png or jpg...how can i get the path then